# Why this causes an infinity loop?

Tags: c++

```
for (unsigned u = 10; u >= 0; --u)
        std::cout << u << std::endl;
```

I know that unsigned cannot be less than `0` I expected it prints from 10 through 0 because `u >= 0`

Comment: condition u = 0 will always exist and that's why an infinite loop

Comment: If you know that unsigned integers are never less than 0, I don't see why you expect `u >= 0`to evaluate to `false` at any point.

Comment: `I know that unsigned cannot be less than 0` There's your answer. `u` will always be `>= 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// WRONG: u can never be less than 0; the condition will always succeed
for (unsigned u = 10; u >= 0; --u)
std::cout << u << std::endl;
```

Consider what happens when `u` is `0`. On that iteration, we’ll print `0` and then execute the expression in the for loop. That expression, `--u`, subtracts `1` from `u`. That result, -1, won’t fit in an unsigned value. As with any other out-of-range value, `-1` will be transformed to an unsigned value. Assuming `32`-bit ints, the result of `--u`, when `u`
is `0`, is `4294967295`. 
 
One way to write this loop is to use a while instead of a for. Using a while lets us decrement before (rather than after) printing our value:

```
unsigned u = 11; // start the loop one past the first element we want to print
while (u > 0) {
--u; // decrement first, so that the last iteration will print 0
std::cout << u << std::endl;
}
```

This loop starts by decrementing the value of the loop control variable. On the last iteration, `u` will be 1 on entry to the loop. We’ll decrement that value, meaning that we’ll print `0` on this iteration. When we next test u in the while condition, its value will be `0` and the loop will exit. Because we start by decrementing `u`, we have to initialize u to a value one greater than the first value we want to print. Hence, we initialize u to `11`, so that the first value printed is `10`.

Answer (score 0):

You decrement `u` each iteration. `u` ends up being `0`, `u >= 0` still holds `true` so another iteration decerements `u` again. The unsigned integer wraps around (because unsigned integers can't be negative) and you get `u == numeric_limits<unsigned>::max`, rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

If you think of this from another perspective this becomes clear.

The condition for the for loop is `u >= 0`. The for loop will stop looping when this is false.

`u` cannot be less than 0, as you know. When you decrement it when it is 0 it will wrap back up again, so `u >= 0` is always true.

So `u >= 0` is never false.

So the for loop is infinite.

If you want to print 10 to 0, you can just use another data type.

Answer (score 0):

In the code block

```
for (unsigned u = 10; u >= 0; --u)
     std::cout << u << std::endl;
```

`u` is unsigned integer and try to find its range which is  `0 to 4294967295`. and `u>=0` always true So condition never fails which causes loop to run finitely.

```
     u = 10            ,  10 >=0     => true => prints 10
     ..
when u = 0             ,  0>=0       => true => prints 0
     u = 4294967295    ,  4294967295 >=0 true ( it will not -1 > 0 as there is no -1 in the range of unsigned int )
```

Meanwhile if you rotate loop 10 times, keep the condition like `u>0` as

```
for (unsigned u = 10; u > 0; --u)
     std::cout << u << std::endl;
```